# MySQL connection issue in gcloud

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have deployed codeigniter project in google cloud app engine . I am getting database connection problem. Database connection is below -

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/tastyeater-190406:us-central1:tastyeater;dbname= databasename',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => 'databasename',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I am getting following error -

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Unable to find the socket
>   transport "unix" -

did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

If I change hostname "localhost" by instance IP address then I am getting following error -

> message: mysqli::real_connect(): (hy000/2002): connection timed out

Please help.

Comment: Check this url :- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/o_rmiMFtcs8

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?